# Test file to check if server meets requirements for Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I am new to Magento and I would like to find out if my server supports Magento 2.0. Any one know of a PHP-file I can upload to my server to find out if I my server have all the requirements for a Magento 2.0 installation?

I have found test files for earlier versions of Magento, but non for Magento 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 installer checks its requirements automatically.